# HTTPS traffic inspection and logging in Clear OS

Tags: clearos

I want to log all https websites accessed from browsers in the network on Clear OS. Looking at their documentation they mention that this feature is not available in Clear OS by default.

Is there any method to decrypt and log https traffic on Clear OS. (This is for monitoring purpose).
(Eg: Visiting  “en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software documentation” should not be logged just as “en.wikipedia.org”. Need the full url).

Any methods to achieve this in Clear OS ?

Comment: The [web proxy documentation](https://documentation.clearos.com/content:en_us:7_ug_web_proxy) seems to hint that this may not possible with tools provided by ClearOS. Which makes sense, since HTTPS is specifically designed to help prevent eavesdropping.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sir, Is there a way to enable/configure SSL Inspection/SSL Bump? By installing any third-party packages/tools?

Comment: Offhand, I am not aware of any way to do this specifically in ClearOS. But supposedly ClearOS is based on CentOS, so maybe a tool like [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) might work?